# Producer Consumer segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, operating-system, segmentation-fault, producer-consumer

Hi im trying to do the producer/consumer problem on a ubuntu virtual image using vmware. I got the code from here : http://macboypro.wordpress.com/2009/05/25/producer-consumer-problem-using-cpthreadsbounded-buffer/ but i just keep getting "segmentation fault (core dumped)". Any help would be great or even a more clean solution to the producer/consumer problem (bounded buffer problem).

Heres the code im using but due to errors i had to take out the '#include "buffer.h"' :

```
            /* buffer.h */
        typedef int buffer_item;
        #define BUFFER_SIZE 5

        /* main.c */

        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <pthread.h>
        #include <semaphore.h>
        #include "buffer.h"

        #define RAND_DIVISOR 100000000
        #define TRUE 1

        /* The mutex lock */
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;

        /* the semaphores */
        sem_t full, empty;

        /* the buffer */
        buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

        /* buffer counter */
        int counter;

        pthread_t tid;       //Thread ID
        pthread_attr_t attr; //Set of thread attributes

        void *producer(void *param); /* the producer thread */
        void *consumer(void *param); /* the consumer thread */

        void initializeData() {

           /* Create the mutex lock */
           pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

           /* Create the full semaphore and initialize to 0 */
           sem_init(&full, 0, 0);

           /* Create the empty semaphore and initialize to BUFFER_SIZE */
           sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

           /* Get the default attributes */
           pthread_attr_init(&attr);

           /* init buffer */
           counter = 0;
        }

        /* Producer Thread */
        void *producer(void *param) {
           buffer_item item;

           while(TRUE) {
              /* sleep for a random period of time */
              int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
              sleep(rNum);

              /* generate a random number */
              item = rand();

              /* acquire the empty lock */
              sem_wait(&empty);
              /* acquire the mutex lock */
              pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

              if(insert_item(item)) {
                 fprintf(stderr, " Producer report error condition\n");
              }
              else {
                 printf("producer produced %d\n", item);
              }
              /* release the mutex lock */
              pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
              /* signal full */
              sem_post(&full);
           }
        }

        /* Consumer Thread */
        void *consumer(void *param) {
           buffer_item item;

           while(TRUE) {
              /* sleep for a random period of time */
              int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
              sleep(rNum);

              /* aquire the full lock */
              sem_wait(&full);
              /* aquire the mutex lock */
              pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
              if(remove_item(&item)) {
                 fprintf(stderr, "Consumer report error condition\n");
              }
              else {
                 printf("consumer consumed %d\n", item);
              }
              /* release the mutex lock */
              pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
              /* signal empty */
              sem_post(&empty);
           }
        }

        /* Add an item to the buffer */
        int insert_item(buffer_item item) {
           /* When the buffer is not full add the item
              and increment the counter*/
           if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
              buffer[counter] = item;
              counter++;
              return 0;
           }
           else { /* Error the buffer is full */
              return -1;
           }
        }

        /* Remove an item from the buffer */
        int remove_item(buffer_item *item) {
           /* When the buffer is not empty remove the item
              and decrement the counter */
           if(counter > 0) {
              *item = buffer[(counter-1)];
              counter--;
              return 0;
           }
           else { /* Error buffer empty */
              return -1;
           }
        }

        int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
           /* Loop counter */
           int i;

           /* Verify the correct number of arguments were passed in */
           if(argc != 4) {
              fprintf(stderr, "USAGE:./main.out <INT> <INT> <INT>\n");
           }

           int mainSleepTime = atoi(argv[1]); /* Time in seconds for main to sleep */
           int numProd = atoi(argv[2]); /* Number of producer threads */
           int numCons = atoi(argv[3]); /* Number of consumer threads */

           /* Initialize the app */
           initializeData();

           /* Create the producer threads */
           for(i = 0; i < numProd; i++) {
              /* Create the thread */
              pthread_create(&tid,&attr,producer,NULL);
            }

           /* Create the consumer threads */
           for(i = 0; i < numCons; i++) {
              /* Create the thread */
              pthread_create(&tid,&attr,consumer,NULL);
           }

           /* Sleep for the specified amount of time in milliseconds */
           sleep(mainSleepTime);

           /* Exit the program */
           printf("Exit the program\n");
           exit(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct, except that you don't have prototypes at the top for:

```
int insert_item(buffer_item item);
int remove_item(buffer_item *item);
```

I was able to run your program without getting a seg fault after adding those prototypes.  Using `rand()` in a multithreaded app is somewhat dangerous though.  When I ran the code with multiple producers, they were all sleeping the same random time and generating the same random item numbers.